# Python3.3 получение атрибутов json

Tags: python, json

Добрый день, срочно нужна помощь. Получаю запись в формате json. Фишка в том, что я не знаю какие там будут атрибуты. Например:

```
u = {'xt': '4', 'title': 'бла-бла'}
f = json.loads(u)
print(f['xt'])
```

результат:

4

Но есть вариант, что в ответе такого атрибута не будет. Как проверить есть ли он? Как можно пробежаться по атрибутам? Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: можно делать
str(f).find('xt'), к примеру, но хотелось бы пробегаться по атрибутам.

Comment: В Вашем случае loads вернет кортеж:  

    if "xt" in f.keys():
        ...

Answer (score 1):

посмотрите команду "get"